# Convert a string using regex_replace filter python and ansible

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, linux, ansible

i would convert all the lines here `@cat\n@chicken\napple\nfruit\njuice` into `+ : @cat : all\n+ :@chicken: all\n+ :apple : all\n+ : fruit : all\njuice : all` in other hand i would get this for every line `+ : value : all`

i would use `regex_replace` filter to perform the task, i don't have too much knowledge on `python`, i am trying to do this:

`{{ '@cat\n@chicken\napple\nfruit\njuice'| regex_replace('^(?P<name>)$', '\\g<name>: ALL' , multiline=True, ignorecase=True)}}` but nothing happens, i am missing something here

Comment: `^(?P<name>)$` is a pattern that only matches an empty string.

Comment: thank you for the clarification so what you think is missing there?

Comment: Try `regex_replace(r'.+', r'+ : \g<0> : all' )`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work there is something missing maybe quoting

Comment: `regex_replace('.+', '+ : \\g<0> : all' )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
regex_replace(r'.+', r'+ : \g<0> : all' )
```

to wrap each non-empty line with `+ : <line_here> : all` text.

Note that `.` matches CR chars, too, and if the line endings are CRLF, you will have to replace `.` with `[^\r\n]`.

Here, `\g<0>` is a replacement backreference to the whole match value, no need using named capturing groups.